# Find $\log_{12}{60}$ if there is given $\log_{6}30$=a and $\log_{15}24$=b

Tags: logarithms

Can someone help me to find $\log_{12}{60}$ if there is given $\log_{6}30$=a and $\log_{15}24$=b?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: The notation log(a,b) is unclear to me.

Comment: Did you mean$$\log_{12}(60)$$?$\quad$

Comment: how is this to be read  $$\log_{12} 60$$?

Comment: Yeah I didn't know how to write that

Comment: Please see here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\log_{12}(60)=\log_{12}(2^{a-1})-a$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hints: Fill in details

$$\begin{align*}
&\log_{12}60=\frac{\log_660}{\log_612}=\frac{\log_65}{1+\log_62}+1\\{}\\
&\log_{15}24=\frac{\log_624}{\log_615}=\frac{1+2\log_62}{1+\log_65-\log_62}\\{}\\
&\log_630=1+\log_65\end{align*}$$

And now just substitute (why and how?):

$$\log_65=a-1\;,\;\;b(a-\log_62)=1+2\log_62\implies (b+2)\log_62=ab-1\;\ldots$$